# Angular2 Injected custom service is undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to inject one custom service(***MessageService***) into another custom service(***ItemService***). It throwing an error ***MessageService*** is undefied in ***ItemService***.
But both the Services (MessageService and ItemService) are working fine with components.

**mani.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { routing, routedComponents } from './app.routing';
import { ItemService } from './services/item.service';
import { MessageService } from './services/message.service';
import './rxjs-extensions';


@NgModule({
  imports:      
  [ BrowserModule, 
    routing, 
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,

  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, routedComponents],
  providers: [
    MessageService,ItemService 
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**message.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Message } from '../models/message';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    constructor() { }

    showError(msg: string) {
        console.log('MessageService Alert::'+msg);
    }

}
```

**item.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Item } from '../models/item';
import { MessageService } from '../services/message.service'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
private restUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/';  // URL to web api

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private msgService: MessageService) { }

  getAllItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.restUrl+'items')
      .map( (res: Response) => res.json() as Item[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    let errorMsg = error.message || error;
    this.msgService.showError("errorMsg"); // msgService is undefined here.
    return Promise.reject(errorMsg);
  }

}
```

here the msgService is undefined in ItemService.
can anyone help me to resolve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `this.` not `ItemService`

```
.catch(this.handleError);
```

should be

```
.catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

for `this.` to keep pointing to the current class instance inside `handleError()`

Comment: oh i see.. but if i do so getting typescript error as 'Observable<{}> is not assignable to type 'Observable<Item[]>'. still i couldn't make progress.

Comment: I don't use TypeScript myself and don't know about generics in TS (in Plunker they are not checked). Perhaps `.map<Object,Item[]>( (res: Response) => res.json() as Item[])`.

Comment: changing `.catch( res => {
        this.messageService.showAlert(res);
        return Observable.throw(res); 
      });` is worked :-)